# Does bleed that stack with itself exist under a larger, existing bleed?

Tags: pathfinder-1e

So, I believe that HP Bleed, in general, can not stack with HP Bleed. So, only the highest bleed works. This brings up several similar and related questions.

Anyway, I was reading over the Spheres of Power (some sort of casting system for Pathfinder). Seems cool. There's this one spell though:

> Razor Claws: Choose one type of natural attack that does piercing or slashing damage (bite, claw, etc.). This type of natural attack deal 1 point of bleed damage plus 1 per 5 caster levels. This bleed damage stacks with itself but not other sources of bleed damage.

1) For simplicity's sake, let's say the target already has a 6 point bleed from another source. Can this stacking bleed damage ever build up, or is it always overridden by being a 1 point bleed?

2) What about for the case of a 1d6 point bleed? The online reference says you're supposed to roll each turn for it. How are you supposed to know which bleed is "bigger."

3) What if there are multiple bleeds with different dice rolls?

4) If the dice rolls come up 1, and you had a 2 damage flat bleed, do you no longer roll, and just take the flat one from then on?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. If you have a 6 point bleed and then a 1 point per round stacking bleed, then for 6 rounds you have 6 bleed, on round 7 you have 7 bleed, etc.  It's just the larger of 6 vs 1 * n.
2. The bigger number is bigger.  If you have 1d6 bleed and a 1 point per round stacking bleed, then each round your bleed is the larger of 1d6 vs 1 * n.
3. Same thing, roll both, see which result is larger.
4. No, nothing about having the second source of bleed interacts with the first source. And if one of the sources is taken away because it depends on some ongoing effect, the other bleed keeps on going.

In general you're confusing the source of the effect and the result.  With bleed they don't stack, you take the best - they are two completely different sources, but you only take the largest number of the results of the non-stacking bleeds.

Comment: OK. That makes sense. In essence, yes, lesser bleeds do exist while larger ones do, they just don't generally matter.