# Does Bleed Damage stack with itself from different sources?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, damage, stacking

Does bleed damage stack with itself from multiple sources?

Comment: Related: [Does bleed that stack with itself exist under a larger, existing bleed?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/102914/does-bleed-that-stack-with-itself-exist-under-a-larger-existing-bleed)

Answer (score 6):

From [the PRD](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/conditions/#TOC-Bleed) (emphasis mine):

> A creature that is taking bleed damage takes the listed amount of damage at the beginning of its turn. Bleeding can be stopped by a DC 15 Heal check or through the application of any spell that cures hit point damage (even if the bleed is ability damage). Some bleed effects cause ability damage or even ability drain. **Bleed effects do not stack with each other unless they deal different kinds of damage**. When two or more bleed effects deal the same kind of damage, take the worse effect. In this case, ability drain is worse than ability damage.